# Liquibase rollback via Maven

Tags: maven, liquibase, rollback

I just started using Liquibase to manage my schema and I'm using the Maven commands to execute Liquibase. I've been successful in updating the schema, however I'm experiencing an issue while testing the rollback feature.

**SQL Format Changelog**

```
--changeset me:create-myschema
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;

--changeset me:create-table1
CREATE TABLE myschema.table1(
  id bigint,
  description varchar(100)
);
--rollback DROP TABLE myschema.table1;

--changeset me:create-table2
CREATE TABLE myschema.table2(
  id bigint,
  code varchar(10)
);
--rollback DROP TABLE myschema.table2;

-- changeset me:tag-1.0
UPDATE databasechangelog SET tag='1.0' WHERE dateexecuted = (SELECT max(dateexecuted) FROM databasechangelog);
```

**Maven Rollback Command**

`mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=1.0`

**Results**

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.1:rollback (default-cli) on project myproject: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase is saying that you don't have a rollback tag defined for the changeset `me:tag-1.0`. Since Liquibase doesn't know that that changeset is a 'tag database' changeset, you would have to tell it that there is no rollback by specifying an empty rollback for that changeset.

```
-- changeset me:tag-1.0
UPDATE databasechangelog SET tag='1.0' WHERE dateexecuted = (SELECT max(dateexecuted) FROM databasechangelog);
-- rollback

-- changeset me:next-change
```

Comment: I added the empty rollback line (e.g. `--rollback`) after the tag database SQL statement and tried the rollback... same issue.

Comment: It may be that you need to just have a "NOP" SQL statement like `select "foo" where 1=1` (may not be valid SQL, but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: Not sure I understand where the no-op statement would go. Are you saying I need this statement after the empty rollback, in the next changeset? What if there is no changeset? If so, seems a bit hackish and incentive to switch to another format (i.e. xml with sql).

Comment: The no-op would be right after the --rollback 'comment'. By the way, my company has a product that wraps and extends liquibase, and we only use the XML format.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mvn liquibase:rollback "-Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1" to rollback latest update.

https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-rollback.html

And

You can just go to your database and find "databasechangelog" table and delete manualy that change row you made with your liquibase script and also delete all changes you made by running liquibase script.